# test whether symbol is an operator

Tags: r, expression

Given a symbol, how do you know if it's an operator?

```
> expr <- quote(a[b + 1] * c)
> expr[[1]]
`*`
```

`match` doesn't work

```
> expr[[1]] %in% c(quote(`+`), quote(`*`))
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

it's possible using `==`

```
> expr[[1]] == quote(`+`)
[1] FALSE
> expr[[1]] == quote(`*`)
[1] TRUE
```

but I wonder if there's an easier way that doesn't involve dozens of `==`'s.

Comment: You could convert the expressions to characters. This works: `as.character(expr[[1]]) %in% c("+", "*")`.